# How to use Sonar TimeLine?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a SonarQube server 5.6 with sonar-scanner 3.0.3 for my projects. I need to have a graphical view of metrics, so I found Sonar TimeLine 1.5 and I installed it.

In SonarQube, I can't find the how to configure or use it. There is no indication in the documentation.

The only documentation I found :

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Timeline+Plugin
- https://blog.sonarsource.com/the-sonar-timeline-plugin-a-great-addition-to-timemachine-service/

How can I use this plug in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The readme](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-timeline) says:

> **Usage**
>
> Add the Advanced Timeline Chart widget to one of your dashboards.

For to add a widget, click on "Configure widgets" in a custom dashboard. See the [official dashboard documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Customizing+Dashboards) for more information.

Background information: customizable dashboards will be dropped in SonarQube 6, but graphical metrics will be part of SonarQube 6.5 "out of the box". (With loads of new features!!!)

See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-870 for more information and nice screenshots!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't know how to add this Advanced Timeline Chart to one of my project. I start with sonar, sorry if the question seems stupid

Comment: @TeddyKossoko I updated my comment. Feel free to ask, if you have any more questions!

Comment: I updated my sonar tp 6.3 to have the new feature "Activity" but I have just the history of buid. Is it normal ? I thought that at the version 6, sonar included graphical metrics in the software !

Comment: @TeddyKossoko I am sorry for this misunderstanding. It will be available in 6.5 and later (not yet released, planned for 4th of August 2017). I hope this did not cause too many inconveniences on your side :(